# How to display contents of file

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to display the contents of a file.

```
class CommonLog
  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename        
  end
  def readfile
    text = File.readlines(@filename).map do |line|
      line.split(" ")
      puts text
    end
  end
end

my_file = CommonLog.new("test.log")
puts my_file.readfile
```

I am receiving the error No such file or directory - test.log".

Comment: As the error says, there is no such file.

Comment: Try passing absolute path to file like `CommonLog.new("full/path/test.log")`

Comment: Also check if `Dir.pwd` gives you error. This happens with me sometimes when I am hooked in old deploy's rails console and the Capistrano revision is no more.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file.  But once you get past that error where the file does not exist, you are doing things that are not worthwhile.

You are splitting the line, but not storing or using the information.

You are using puts to output the return of the text object, but your question title is how to view the contents.

You can `puts line` which will output each line of the file once it exists.

You are assigning text, and referencing it in the same statement, and so when you puts `text` it is `nil`.  The method will return the assignment to text, but otherwise it is not being used.

If you remove the reference to `text` inside the block, you get get rid of the assignment to `text` variable.

Finally, you can remove the entire block if you would simply want an array of lines to be returned, or use `join` on the `readlines` method.

The redesigned version may look like this:

```
class CommonLog
  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
  end
  def readfile
    File.readlines(@filename)
  end
end

my_file = CommonLog.new("test.log")
puts my_file.readfile # This actually prints an Array
```

That array holds the contents of your file, and the puts displays the contents of that file as stored in that array.

Comment: Then I suppose I don't know the meaning of "How to display contents of file" means.

Comment: The title is not the whole question. If you read the body, it says that "[OP is] I am receiving the error No such file or directory - test.log". That's the question.

Comment: That was a statement.

Comment: ...I actually didn't see your comment until after I posted mine. I felt I should clarify on what I said earlier.